# Restore deleted messages from Macbook to iPhone

Tags: messages

I deleted all my texts from my significant other by a mistake on my iPhone and I don't have it backed up by iCloud (my mistake). I have all the texts on my MacBook under Messages. Is there any way I can get them down to my Phone again? Thank you for you help. (I'm desperate, BTW.)

Comment: Do you have your iPhone backed up to the cloud?  You’ll need to restore it before it overwrite the backup done prior to you doing your accidental deletion.  After that, they’re gone.

Answer (score 0):

Set up iCloud messages to sync them from your Mac or restore your phone from a backup. If you set up iCloud messages then if you delete by accident them in the future, they will be gone on all of your devices.